# Kotlin Bytecode doesn't work with Android DataBinding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

here is my code

```
class MainFragment: Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
        val binding: FragmentMainBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater!!, R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
        binding.user = User("Hello World!", 18)
        return binding.root
    }
}
```

and when i open Kotlin Bytecode, it throws an error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZVnM.png)

it seems like that there was something wrong with DataBindingUtil.

how to fix this problem?

Comment: Please post the stacktrace here as text, not as an external image.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? The Kotlin Bytecode toolwindow is a debugging tool which runs the compiler in a special, restricted environment. Even if it doesn't work for your code, it doesn't prevent you from building and running your application.

Comment: @yole I'm trying to convert Kotlin to Java. There is no problem with building or running.

Comment: @m0skit0 thanks for your suggestion, I will post the stacktrace as text when I have time.

Comment: This code is trivial to convert manually, you don't need any tool for that.